# No crear registros duplicados en AWS DynamoDB

Tags: nodejs, aws, dynamodb

Intento que al crear un registro duplicado me muestre un error. Mi PK se crea con el nombre y email del usuario, lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
const newUser = {
    id,
    username: event.body.username,
    ...
}
const params = {
    TableName:"Users",
    Item:newUser,
    ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(id)"
}
try {
    await dynamodb.putItem(params,(err,data)=>{
        if(err) console.log("Error", err);
        else console.log("Created!")
    }).promise()
    return {...}
} catch (error) {
    return {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar crear registros duplicados en AWS DynamoDB y mostrar un error cuando se intenta crear un registro con una clave primaria (PK) existente, puedes utilizar una condición de expresión en la operación putItem. Actualmente, estás utilizando attribute_not_exists(id) como condición de expresión, pero eso solo comprueba si el atributo id no existe.

Para solucionar el problema y evitar duplicados, puedes modificar la condición de expresión para que verifique si la clave primaria compuesta (nombre y email en tu caso) no existe en la tabla. Aquí está el código actualizado:

```
const newUser = {
    id,
    username: event.body.username,
    ...
};

const params = {
    TableName: "Users",
    Item: newUser,
    ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(username) AND attribute_not_exists(email)"
};

try {
    await dynamodb.put(params).promise();
    console.log("Created!");
    return {...};
} catch (error) {
    if (error.code === "ConditionalCheckFailedException") {
        console.log("Registro duplicado: la clave primaria ya existe");
        return {...}; // Devuelve el mensaje de error apropiado o toma otras acciones según tu caso
    }
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return {...}; // Devuelve el mensaje de error apropiado o toma otras acciones según tu caso
}
```

En este código, la condición de expresión attribute_not_exists(username) AND attribute_not_exists(email) verifica que tanto el atributo username como el atributo email no existan en la tabla antes de intentar crear el registro. Si se viola esta condición, se lanzará una excepción de tipo ConditionalCheckFailedException y puedes manejarla para mostrar un mensaje de error adecuado o tomar otras acciones necesarias.

Recuerda adaptar el código según las estructuras y nombres reales de tus atributos de usuario en DynamoDB.

Comment: Asegúrate de [no utilizar ChatGPT](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462): está prohibido aquí.